# What is the maximum number of thread that can be created ? Does system configuration need to be considered when multiThreading

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++, image-processing

What is the maximum thread that i can create for my algorithm ? Does system configuration need to be considered when i use MultiThreading ?

My Hardware : Intel(R) Core (TM)2 Duo CPU E8400 @3.00 GHz 2.00 GHz

Installed RAM : 4.00 GB

How Many maximum threads i can create / or use in my project ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows has no "hardcoded" limit on threads count (I see you marked this question with visual c++ tag, so it is about Windows, is that correct?).
You have to consider your hardware limits only; first of all, default thread stack size is 1 megabyte, so when you create thread you at least need 1 megabyte of memory just for stack, additionally most probably your custom code will allocate some memory. Also contexts switching is not easy job for OS. There is no sense often to create more threads than processors cores count unless threads have to wait for some long operation like HTTP request.
So, ideally you have to double think before thread creation, but if you are sure you need threads, don't care about any limits except memory and CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of [If you have to ask, you're probably doing it wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx). Creating threads carries a cost and you/OS quickly end up spending more time managing the threads than you gain from parallelising the task.

The best approach to take is to determine the number of CPUs and limit the number of threads you create to the number of CPUs. By CPU I mean a hardware execution unit.